# Mulesoft not able to pass dynamic SQL queries based on environments

Tags: sql, database, environment-variables, mulesoft, anypoint-studio

Hello for demonstration purposes I trimmed out my actual sql query.

I have a SQL query

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbdev.training.courses
```

where `dbdev` is my DEV database table name. When I migrate to TEST env, I want my query to dynamically change to

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbtest.training.courses
```

I tried using input parameters like `{env: p('db_name')}` and using in the query as

```
SELECT * FROM :env.training.courses
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM (:env).training.courses
```

but none of them worked. I don't want my SQL query in properties file.

Can you please suggest a way to write my SQL query dynamically based on environment?

The only alternative way is to deploy separate jars for different environments with different code.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value of the property to a variable and then use the variable with string interpolation.

**Warning**: creating dynamic SQL queries using any kind of string manipulation may expose your application to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) **security vulnerabilities**.

Example:

```
#['SELECT * FROM $(vars.database default "dbtest").training.courses']
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can do a completely dynamic or partially dynamic query using the MuleSoft DB connector.

Please see this repo:
https://github.com/TheComputerClassroom/dynamicSQLGETandPATCH

Also, I'm about to post an update that allows joins.

At a high level, this is a "Query Builder" where the code that builds the query is written in DataWeave 2. I'm working on another version that allows joins between entities, too.

If you have questions, feel free to reply.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is :

1. Create a variable before DB Connector:
   getTableName - ${env}.training.courses
2. Write SQL Query :
   Select * from $(getTableName);